# How to retrieve family from graph API?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I know how to [retrieve family from Facebook using fql](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/family/).  But I can't find how to do so using the much more convenient graph API.  Is there a way or is fql the only way to find relationships?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via graph API it will be:

https://graph.facebook.com/UID/family

which requires user_relationships/friends_relationships extended permissions

Comment: Excellent, only that it doesn't include family which aren't associated with a facebook profile.  How did you find out about this?  I didn't see it in any of the reference documentation.  I just found it now roaming in the graph api explorer.  Is that how we're expected to find these kinds of objects?

Comment: it is there in the docs, see graph api for user - connections: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/